# Found a set of car keys, now what?

Tags: mercedes-benz, key

I have found what look like Mercedes car keys.

It's a black casing and we can barely see the Mercedes logo.

In the key we can see a "Huf" inscription on both sides and a small Mercedes logo.

I don't think the owner will be lucky enough to see this post (kinda hoping this gets indexed fast and he finds it by looking on google!), so, is there something that can be done to find the owner? I've read that it is very difficult due to privacy issues.

Hope this subject is relevant to this community.

Comment: Post a note on Craigslist. Also contact parts department of local Mercedes Dealer. Let them know if a customer is looking to replace lost keys they can call you first.

Comment: Another suggestion, if you live in a City or particular state, is to find that states/cities subreddit on reddit and post it on there. You'll probably get better local advice for specific lost and found services within your city/state.

Comment: +1 for going to the local dealer. Give them the key; the owner will probably call them shortly for a replacement anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ethical options available to you.

1. Leave a note/poster nearby stating that you have found a lost key
2. Post on social media that you have found a lost key so word gets around
3. Hand in the key to your local Police Station or Lost property

It might also be worth having a look around where you found it to see if there are any possible cars that match and knocking on the door.

There are many free services around now where you can get a keyring so if ever lost someone can just pop it in a post box.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot post a comment so in addidion to Terry:
go to facebook, join a local community (from where you found the key) - something like: buy and sell Philadelphia (no idea if it exists) - post that you found a car key (no too precise description) and ask people to share it in the surrounding area. Hand it to the Lost property or police and include that detail in your post.

Tell police in either way and maybe tell tow and repair services, whoever lost the car key needs to open and tow their car eventually.